# problem with remote printing using rsh

Tags: command-line, printing

This is really a unix/linux problem than an ubuntuproblem, so perhaps this is the wrong forum, but I'll post it anyway.

when I type the commandline command

```
rsh -l <myName> <IPADDRESS> /usr/bin/lpr -#2 <filename>
```

I get the following puzzling, rather unhelpful error

```
/usr/bin/lpr: Error - unknown option "
```

The remote command works fine without the -# flag, and locally the lpr command works fine with the -# flag, so it must have something to do with the way rsh processes the # sign.

Could anybody advise please?

Thanks very much for any assistance!

Comment: The usage of `rsh` is strongly discouraged on Ubuntu. Do you have possibilities to try `ssh`, its recommended secure alternative?